# Select counts values using inner join in SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Select counts values using inner join in SQL

I have two tables:

1. `application_info`
2. `application_movement`

When user will apply for the job, then details will inserted into the `application_info` table and HR activities like hold candidate, decline, shortlist and schedule will updated in the `application_movement` table.

`application_info`:

```
applicationId    appliedjobID    emailID               status
-------------------------------------------------------------------
     1                3          usercandi@gmail.com   pending
     2                9          user2@gmail.com       pending
     3                2          user3@gmail.com       pending
```

`applicaiton_movement`:

```
ApplicationId  Fromstatus  toStatus         movementemailID
--------------------------------------------------------
1                pending      hold             hr@gmail.com
1                hold        **decline**       hr@gmail.com
2                pending      shortlist        hr1@gmail.com
2                shortlist   **scheduled**     hr1@gmail.com
3                pending     **scheduled**     hr@gmail.com
```

HR will do hold, decline, shortlist and scheduled, I need counts of hr@gmail.com and hr1@gmail.com (how many activities did by her counts like hold, decline, shortlist and a scheduled interview from `tostatus` column)

In `application_movement`, `ApplicationID` are two or more times.. So need a count of the last updated `tostatus` count only..

```
  i.e   hr@gmail.com     decline(1)   scheduled(1)  

        hr1@gmail.com    scheduled(1)
```

Just need select query base on two tables of `applicationId` fetch the counts.

Comment: You do not seem to have information in your sample tables about which is the last status.  Do you have a datetime stamp or something to get the last one?

Comment: Ya i have datetime like createddatetime fields in both the tables.

Comment: toStatus is last field from application_movement and count should come from toStatus. Fromstatus is our understanding to know user status flow.

Comment: You should add a datetime column to your table. It will make your life so.much easier you wont believe.

Comment: ya i have already datetime column name datetime column but above not mention please send me answer select query.

Comment: SELECT LAST(toStatus) FROM applicaiton_movement group by createddatetime ;    i think will work this query.